# discrete math monotonic functions question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

i had this question to answer:

how many monotonic function $f:[1...k]\to[1...n]$, $(i>j \implies f(i)\geqslant f(j))$ are there?

my answer is: $\sum_{r_1=1}^n\sum_{r_2=r_1}^n\cdots\sum_{r_k=r_{k-1}}^n1$

is this the right answer?

Thanks in advance,

Yaron

Answer (score 3):

After correction, your iterated summation formula describes the correct number, but it is not really an answer. You are saying there are as many monotonic functions $f[1,k]\to[1,n]$ as there are sequences $r_1,\ldots,r_k$ with $1\leq r_1\leq r_2\leq\cdots\leq r_k\leq n$, which is true because taking $r_i=f(i)$ for $i\in[1,k]$ establishes a bijection.

If you want to know what that number is, you many want to establish a bijection with something that you know how to count in terms of some simple expression in $k$ and $n$ (not an iterated summation). Here is an idea: if you define $s_i=r_i+(i-1)$ for $i\in[1,k]$, then you get a sequence $1\leq s_1< s_2<\cdots< s_k\leq n+k-1$ and the correspondence $(r_1,\ldots,r_k)\mapsto(s_1,\ldots,s_k)$ is a bijection since setting $r_i=s_i-(i-1)$ for $i\in[1,k]$ inverts it. You many know a formula for the number of such sequences $s_1,\ldots,s_k$.

Hint: $\{s_1,\ldots,s_k\}$ is a combination of $k$ elements chosen in the set $[1,n+k-1]$, and any combination of $k$ such elements occurs exactly once in this way.

Comment: hi, thank you very much, i understand the problem, but i didn't understand how to solve it.

Comment: Will the additional hint help?

Comment: got it, great answer. is the solution $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: thank you very much man :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to switch your k's and n's.

You have k inputs that you need to choose outputs for and the largest each of these could be is n while the lowest they can be is the output of the previous input.

Comment: that's what i meant, thanks.
other than that it's ok?

Comment: yes, other than that it's fine

Comment: You're welcome.